# escape symbol using mybatis

Tags: oracle, escaping, mybatis, ibatis

i have a dynamic query on my batis and i need to escape the % symbol.

this is part of my query (i've tried a lot of different combinations)

```
<choose>
            <!-- Titulo     -->     
            <when test="titulo != null">                            
                lower(p.titulo) like '%'||\||#{titulo}||'%' ESCAPE '\'
```

this is what i need:

```
select * from publicaciones where titulo like '%/%%' escape '/';  //this works perfect in oracle.
```

what would be the right syntax for that query in mybatis??

Comment: have you tried using &#37 as a percent sign? I am not sure where is the problem exactly as I am new to mybatis but once I resolved a similar problem with this substitution. http://www.dvteclipse.com/documentation/svlinter/How_to_use_special_characters_in_XML.3F.html

Answer (score 0):

Lets say i want to write the next query: 
`select * from employees where emp_id < 100`

The `<` cause problems.
You have 2 options: 
The easiest is to use the ASCII code of the character u want. 
It's ASCII value is 60 (you can look for it at [here](http://ascii.cl/) or any other ASCII table.).
So replacement of '<' will be: '&#(ASCII_VALUE);' which is '<'
and i will write the next query instead:
`select * from employees where emp_id &#60; 100`

the other option is to use CDATA as shown [here](http://ibatis.apache.org/docs/dotnet/datamapper/ch03s03.html#id379334) 
`

```
<statement id="SelectPersonsByAge" parameterClass="int" resultClass="Person">
  <![CDATA[ 
     SELECT * FROM PERSON WHERE AGE > #value# 
  ]]>
</statement>`
```